QGIS showing extra vertical lines when using Natural Earth graticules
3.36 and trying to use the graticule shape file from natural earth for the area around the United Kingdom using the CRS EPSG:27700
I filtered the built in world shape file for the UK and then changed the projects projection to EPSG:27700
This is the first time I have tried to use the graticules.  Which I import as a vector layer.
The graticules seem to show 2 projections some how?  I have added the degrees to the label for the graticule layer.
It shows the graticules with the curvature but also perfectly straight lines on the vertical?
How do I remove these vertical lines?


Incluce a link to the file you use (edit your initial post). Otherwise, we don't know about what exactly you speak.

From the look of the labels those lines are on the other side of the Earth, you need to clip the graticules to the area around the UK.
